# Display div half the time

Tags: php, html

I'd like to display a div half the time. I thought about something like this :

Generate a number with : `$nb = rand(0,1);`
Then, for my div, I use a condition `if:$nb == 0`, it shows, if it is 1, it doesn't.

What do you think ? 
Is there a easiest way because it looks a little untidy...

Comment: `mt_rand` is better apparently - see more here: [PHP rand() …get true 50/50 results?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658357/php-rand-get-true-50-50-results)

Comment: what dou you mean by "half the time"? Half time of what?

Comment: Actually your code only shows the div on half the pageviews, not half the time. You should use `if(time() & 1)` to really have it display half the time.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers ! @NielsKeurentjes That was my idea but what is the difference betweek half the pageviews and half the time ? Thank you !

Comment: If you get 1000 pageviews per hour, the `rand` based code will show the div about 500 times. The `time` based approach only shows it on odd seconds, which might be 1, 250, 500 or 900 times depending on when the visitors exactly hit a link to your site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should post such questions on [codereview.SE]

2. You can simplify your code to this:

```
if (rand(0,1)) {
   //Show the div
}
```

0 will be converted to false, while 1 is being converted to true.

Comment: yes, but there is more opportunity for improvement using `mt_rand`.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the simplification! This is what I looked for!

Answer (score 2):

It's fine. If you're lookin for another way to do it use javascript :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(Math.round(Math.random())==1) {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display='none';
} else {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display='block';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sir! It is very useful to have different way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

```
(gettimeofday()["usec"] % 2 == 1)
```

could be your randomization. `gettimeofday()["usec"]` is the current millisecond and we look at it whether it is odd or not.